# Trigger Dynamic Button Id using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP table generated using a MySQL database, I want to run a jquery function by clicking on a button placed in a field in the table. Since the button id is dynamic, Is there a way to trigger the button id and run the jQuery?

**PHP Code :**

```
echo "<td>
<button id='".$row['S_No']."'value='".$row['S_No'].">".$row['S_No']."</button></td>";
```

**JQuery Code:**

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#buttonId").click(function(){
      // Code goes here
  });
});
```

Comment: Don't use an ID, use a class. `<button class="js-myfunc" ... other php stuff... />`  then `$('.js-myfunc').on('click', // code );`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use class instead id

```
echo "<td>
<button class="btn-class" id='".$row['S_No']."'value='".$row['S_No'].">".$row['S_No']."</button></td>";

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn-class").click(function(){
      // Code goes here
  });
});
```

Comment: Worked as a charm! Thank you! much appreciated :)